# How to view file descriptors for all processes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to write a bash script that shows to me how many processes are currently using the file descriptor 2 (stderr) (ALL processes that are currently running). I've tried with lsof -d 2 already and the counting of /proc/*/fd/2 directories didn't help either.Is there another command or how am I supposed to check this?

Comment: How exactly the commands _didn't help_?

Comment: It returned a value that is not correct. There are less/more processes that use that descriptor.

Comment: This may help: http://serverfault.com/questions/485262/number-of-file-descriptors-different-between-proc-sys-fs-file-nr-and-proc-pi

Comment: It would really help to post sample output and provide expected output to support your question

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing magical about file descriptor numbers, typically 2 is used for stderr but it can point to a file or pty or etc depending on what the process does. Also processes can close descriptors at any time.

Try as root: `lsof -d 2` should give an approximation of all processes with a descriptor 2.

Comment: Hello can I use lsof -d * to find out the total number of global open files / filedescriptors ? What I get in the `FD` column is for process a) `3ww` and for process b) `25u` ??